# jar to python module

Tags: java, python, jar, port

I am using an API which provides a Java version but not a Python version.
I can switch to Java as right now I am only prototyping.

but is there a quick way to convert the functionality of API packaged in a jar to a python module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look into [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)?

Comment: I have heard the word Jython but did not know what it was for. I will test it out. thanks